# getAccessToken returns the app access token instead of the user access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

First im getting the "login url":

```
if (!$facebook->getUser())
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream' 
    ));
}
```

And redirect to it, if the user not login it requests him to log in,
If the user need to authorize the App, it will request him to do that as well.

The problem is that after the user authorized the App and redirected to my redirect_uri,
I still can get his token in order to fetch information about him.
This:

```
$facebook->getAccessToken()
```

Returns the App access token (the one with the pipe in the middle)
and this:
    $facebook->getUser()
return 0.
and im ending with an endless loop which requesting the login url (first time it will request to authorize my APP) an redirect to my redirect_uri which requesting it again because 
    $facebook->getUser()
returning 0.

And the funny part is:
When i use this code on other server (located elsewhere in the world) it works.
And when i try this on other server (in even other location in the world) it works only 60% of the time.

Where is the problem? in my code? in my server? in Facebook?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

try using `$facebook->getAccessTokenFromCode($_GET['code'])` instead.

Comment: Thank you,This was not the solution but it provide me an error which lead me to it.
The problem was that the redirect_uri was difrent from the the url that perform the loginurl request.

Comment: the code is given only the first time the user logs into the app. so how to fetch it/renew it rest later times?

Answer (score 0):

I have also at sometimes encountered this problem. What turned out that, during those times I was using Facebook as a page of the same app not using as my usual profile. So whenever you face this problem you can check to **make sure that you are using Facebook as a user profile not any page**.

I hope this will at least save some frustration to someone in future, so answered although your problem is solved.